# Nopcommerce MessageTemplate, can't add method as token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, nopcommerce

I'm making a MessageTemplate in nopCommerce and I want to add a token that implements a method from another class.

In the class "ProductService" I have a method called "DailyBestsellersReport" which I want to add as a token for my MessageTemplate in "MessageTokenProvider". However when I add "ProductService" as a reference in the MessageTokenProvider it tells me the method "DailyBestsellerReport" isn't valid in the current context which have me thinking there's a syntax error somewhere.
This is the method I want to add as token:

ProductService class:

```
public IList<BestsellersReportLine> DailyBestSellersReport(
    int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1)
{
    var yesterDay = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
    var earliest = new DateTime(yesterDay.Year, yesterDay.Month, yesterDay.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    var latest = earliest.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, -1));
    var currentDay = DateTime.Now;
    var dayBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    
    
        var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                 where earliest <= currentDay && latest >= dayBefore
                 join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                 join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                 join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                 select opv;


        var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
            //group by product variants
               from opv in query1
               group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
               select new
               {
                   EntityId = g.Key,
                   TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                   TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
               }
               :
            //group by products
               from opv in query1
               group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
               select new
               {
                   EntityId = g.Key,
                   TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                   TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
               }
               ;

        switch (orderBy)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
        }

        if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
            query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

        var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
        {
            var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
            {
                EntityId = x.EntityId,
                TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
            };
            return reportLine;
        }).ToList();

        return result;
}
```

I want to add "DailyBestsellersReport" here:

MessageTokenProvider class

```
public void AddReportTokens(IList<Token> tokens, BestsellersReportLine DailyBestSellersReport, ProductService productService, int languageId)
{
    tokens.Add(new Token("BestsellersReportLine.EntityId", DailyBestSellersReport.EntityId.ToString()));
    tokens.Add(new Token("BestsellersReportLine.TotaAmount", DailyBestSellersReport.TotalAmount.ToString()));
    tokens.Add(new Token("BestsellersReportLine.TotalQuantity", DailyBestSellersReport.TotalQuantity.ToString()));

    tokens.Add(new Token("ProductService.DailyBestSellersReport", productService.DailyBestSellersReport.ToString)());
}
```

When I add:

```
tokens.Add(new Token("ProductService.DailyBestSellersReport", productService.DailyBestSellersReport.ToString)());
```

It tell me:

> Error 10  'Nop.Services.Catalog.ProductService.DailyBestSellersReport(int, int, int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

I've also added tokens from "BestsellersReportLine" class which works fine, however these are properties and not methods like:

```
public partial class BestsellersReportLine
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself tells the solution how can you call a method without passing any arguments to it when it accepts parameters.

You will need to write method which returns string depending on result in of `productService.DailyBestSellersReport`

```
public string ReturnTable()
{
    var report = productService.DailyBestSellersReport(param1,param2,param2)
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    foreach (var r in report)
    {    
        // I believe you are trying to build HTML table so you can append any string here to sb   
    }
    return sb.ToString();    
}
```

Then use

```
tokens.Add(new Token("ProductService.DailyBestSellersReport",ReturnTable());

sb.AppendLine("<table border=\"0\" style=\"width:100%;\">");//sb is stringbuilder's object

sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<tr style=\"background-color:{0};text-align:center;font-size:12px; \">", _templatesSettings.Color1));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<th>Sr. No.</th>"));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<th>Item1</th>"));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<th>Item2</th>"));
sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

// Header is closed
// Next is data which will be created using foreach on data from `IList<BestsellersReportLine>`
foreach (var item in result)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<tr style=\"background-color: {0};text-align: center;\">", _templatesSettings.Color2));
              // you can place all your data in below tds, you can create any number of tds.
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<td style=\"padding: 0.6em 0.4em;text-align: right;\">{0}</td>", item.Prop1));
    sb.AppendLine("<td style=\"padding: 0.6em 0.4em;text-align: left;\">" + item.Prop2);
    sb.AppendLine("</td>");
    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}
sb.AppendLine("</table>"); // don't forget to close table

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I see thanks. Would it be appropriate to write "Returnable()" in ProductServices after "DailyBestSellersReport()" method or should i write it somewhere else? I Suspect the "params" would be the properties of DailyBestSellersReport: "int RecordsToReturn, int OrderBy, int GroupBy as it complained about the properties being "int, int, int". Thx

Comment: If you are going to have that function limited to that class only you can have it there only. And yes params are what u r saying

Comment: That actually makes sence =) Do you know where i can find example code of a html Table. I need to make one but i'm not sure how, iv'e just looked at the excisting code in MessageTemplate and MessageTokenProvider.

Comment: Have u checked in MessageToken provider i think there is some method for this. if you couldnt find i can give u similar king of code from my side. let me know

Comment: Looked up MessageTokenProvider but couldn't find any example of html table. Also wondering what the stringbuilder should do, is it suposed to format a string?

Comment: stringbuilder is supposed to hold formatted strings which are table rows table data ,images etc

Comment: Just figured i forgot adding system.text in namespace. Stringbuilder class implements accordingly. Thx

Comment: Alright. How would i go about adding a table in the foreach loop?